# How to access inputs attributes in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Or simpler, how do I implement an equivalent of the code below in node js?

```
selectedRadio = document.querySelector('input[name="device"]:checked').dataset.name;
```

I'm using Node js for backend of an app with Express.js and BodyParser.

I was able to access HTML elements with their Names with `req.body.elementName`, but I have trouble getting value from the code above.

Comment: You can't. Server-client.

Comment: Show us how you send the request to your backend. We might be able to improve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DOM doesn't exist in Node. There is no `body` or `document` because there is no website in the backend. That means accessing a DOM element by `document.querySelector()` will not work because `document` doesn't exist.

You should be passing the **values directly** to your Node application, instead of passing HTML Elements.

Comment: I obviously know it doesn't have DOM but as you can see I was able to access the DOM and get data with req.body so I was looking for a way to access a set of radio buttons' selected value.

Comment: @AhmetÖmer: You were not able to access the DOM. Some form data was converted to text and sent to your application. Look in your browser’s Network panel for the exact contents.

Comment: @AhmetÖmer as I stated, you should be sending the values you want directly. And not send HTML Elements as your requests body.

Comment: That is the problem, I don't know how to send those values @Zammy

Comment: @AhmetÖmer `req.body` sounds to me like you are getting some kind of request (AJAX?) from the frontend. You will need to make your adjustments there. If you need help show us the code.

Answer (score 0):

Like Zammy said, there is no DOM. Just try using events for this. 
just give your checkbox the onChange property and add the function you want to handle your event with.

```
<input 
  type="checkbox"
  onChange=YOUR JS_EVENT_CODE
/>
```

There you could bind an existing function or just insert sth. like an arrow function.

Comment: You mean writing that onchange function in Nodejs and then store the value?

Comment: Sure, or just use sth like an arrow function.